# How to fix my laser printer failing to print certain areas?

Tags: hardware-failure, laser-printer

I recently acquired a used HP LaserJet M1217nfw MFP.

When I print the demo page from the settings menu, certain areas of the page fail to be printed. It looks sort of like white stripes through the page.

[image: Example print]

What's the most likely cause of this? Is the laser broken? Is the page-heater-thingy broken? Is something wrong with the ink roller?

**EDIT:** I replaced the printer cartridge and it works fine now.

Comment: It could be low on toner.

Comment: Have you taken the toner cartridge out and rocked it side-to-side to evenly distribute the toner?

Comment: Three possibilities:  1) The toner is low.  2) The ionization gizmo is dirty.  3) The "drum" (which is generally a belt of sorts) is worn out.  See if you can't find the manual online and check instructions for cleaning the ionization gizmo.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I have, and it didn't change anything.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to close the loop.  Could you make your edit an answer, instead (and accept it)?  That will help others with a similar problem and help to maintain the knowledgebase structure of the site (questions are just questions and answers are in answers).  Anyway, glad you got it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like there's dirt or dust inside keeping the laser light from reaching the drum, which results in no ink being applied in those areas.

Check your manuals, there's most likely some cleaning to be done (be careful and follow the instructions).

Answer (score 0):

Measure the defective streaks on the page to determine if the print cartridge might be damaged and needs to replaced.

From HP's help file on checking print cartridges,

"If defects repeat at any of the following intervals on the page, a print cartridge might be damaged.

22 mm
27 mm
29 mm
76 mm"

Good Luck